Can't load WMS services -- Failed to parse capabillities
I can't get data loaded in QGIS. The data is: https://mapsdep.nj.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Features/Environmental_admin/MapServer/22
Is there anyway to get this to work?

add it as a ArcGIS-Rest Layer, not as WMS-Layer and use this URL:  https://mapsdep.nj.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Features/Environmental_admin/MapServer

The mapsdep.nj.gov/arcgis server doesn't support the WMS standard, so you can't load it as a WMS; hence the error.
You can instead load it as an ArcGIS REST Server Layer using https://mapsdep.nj.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Features/Environmental_admin/MapServer/ as the URL, giving:

